# Providing data to Python input() from Bash

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

Given this program named `foo.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
foo = input('input foo: ')
print(foo)
```

How do I run this from `foo_test.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out so thought I'd post it.  Simple, of course:

```
 % echo 'foodata' | ./foo.py
```

That does the job.

Comment: Another way - make a plain text file `input.txt` with content "foodata". Then run `./foo.py < input.txt` But for one simple line, your approach is a lot easier...